# CSS width problem child parent

Tags: css, html, width

I have a div C inside div B inside div A.

Div A has width set to 700px, and div C has width set to 100px. Div B doesn't have the width set.

My problem is that div B extends his width to 100% (to conform div A's width). Is there a way for div B, that is, his width to conform to children divs? I want it to be wrapped around div C, and any other div I put near div C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is the nonexistent float:center attribute.  Check [this article](http://www.wipeout44.com/brain_food/css_staying_afloat.asp) for a workaround.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following code to achieve your result:

```
#b {
  margin:0px auto;
  overflow:hidden;
  display:table;
}
```

This should give your desired result.

Answer (score 3):

Make the B div a floating element to make it's width adjust to it's children.

```
<div id="B" style="float:left;">
```

Comment: Hm, good answer... But I want to position those C divs, so they look like they are in the center of div A. If I put float:left to div B, I will not be able to do that.

Comment: If you want to center the B div it's easily done by setting the left and right margin to auto, but then you need to specify a width for it instead of floating it.

Comment: Yes, but if I add width to div B, then I will not be able to automatically resize it when new divs C are added.